# Need help in bash script and awk command

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I need a bash script to print folder names and file names recursively (in stdo/p).
For example:
i have a folders structure like /earth/plants/flowers/rose/rose.jpg.

```
/earth/plant/fruits/apple/apple.jpg.
/earth/animals/carni/lions.jpg
/earth/animals/herbi/omni/dog.jpg
```

now i need to list this files and folders like this i mean my O/P script should be,

```
planet=earth
category=animal (plant) 
sub cat = carni 
name = lion.jpg.
```

i tried

```
`find / -name "*" -print | awk -F"/" '{ print "\n planet=",$2,"\n category=",$3,"\n sub cat=",$4,"\n Name=",$5, $6 }'`
```

above command gives me following O/P.

```
planet=earth 
category=animal (plant)  
sub cat = carni 
name = lion.jpg
```

But in some cases i've additional folders like "`/earth/animals/herbi/omni/rabbit.jpg`" in this case order is changing in output like:

```
planet=earth 
category=animal 
sub cat = herbi 
name = omni 
rabbit.jpg
```

so i need to list additional subcat in few places . like

```
planet=earth
category=animals
sub cat = herbi
add cat = omni
name = rabbit.jpg
```

so how to do that with a single script.Scripts apart from awk is also welcome.

```
`find / -name "*" -print | awk -F"/" '{ print "\n planet=",$2,"\n category=",$3,"\n sub cat=",$4,"\n Name=",$5,$6}``
```

in this case what ever there in $5 it will print as name only.so need something like this.

```
 ``find / -name "*" -print | awk -F"/" '{ print "\n planet=",$2,"\n category=",$3,"\n sub cat=",$4,"\n add cat =",$5,(if $5 = foldername print  "add cat = omni")  name = $6 }'"``.
```

thanks,
vijai k

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F"/" '{
    print "\n planet=", $2, "\n category=", $3, "\n sub cat=", $4
    for (i = 5; i < NF; i++) print " add cat=", $i
    print " Name=",$NF
}'
```

Comment: Need one more help,if i want to display the size of $NF,what should i do ?

Comment: @vijai: To print the length in characters: `print length($NF)`

Comment: it is showing character count.ex.rabbit.jpg contains 10 chars,so it displaying 10. i need size of that file to printed.like 10kb.

Comment: @vijai: in AWK? `system("stat -c %s " $NF)` if your system has stat. Another way: `system("wc -c <" $NF)`

Answer (score 0):

You could try this - chock full of bashisms, won't work in other shells:

*(find command goes here)* `| while IFS=/ read root planet category rest; do`

```
    echo "planet=$planet"
    echo "category=$category"
    size="$(stat -c %s "/$planet/$category/$rest")"
    while [[ "$rest" == */* ]]; do
       subcat="${rest%%/*}"
       rest="${rest#*/}"
       echo "subcategory=$subcat"
     done
     echo "name=$rest"
     echo "size=$size"
     echo
done
```

Also, `-name "*"` on a find command is redundant.  But you probably want `-type f` at least.