# Need help in bash script

Tags: bash, shell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help in bash script and awk command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10530642/need-help-in-bash-script-and-awk-command)

I need a bash script to print directory names and file names recursively . For example: i have a directory structure like:

```
/earth/plants/flowers/rose/rose.jpg.
/earth/plant/fruits/apple/apple.jpg.
/earth/animals/carni/lions.jpg
/earth/animals/herbi/omni/dog.jpg
```

Now I need to list this files and folders like this — I mean my O/P should be,

```
planet=earth
category=animal (plant) 
sub cat = carni 
name = lion.jpg.
```

In some places I have additional directories also.like `/earth/animals/carni/jungle/lions.jpg`.

Then I need to display that `lions.jpg` file size also.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: There's no obvious way to get 'animal' from `/earth/animals/...`; there's no obvious way to get 'lion.jpg' from `/earth/animals/carni/lions.jpg`.  Computers are demanding objects; you have to be consistent in your spellings.  Also, what are you going to call the fourth level of directory (sub-sub-cat?).

Comment: What's wrong with my answer to your other question? If you have ImageMagick installed, you can call `display filename&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may get you part of the way there...

```
find /earth | sed -e 's/\// /' | awk '{ print "planet = " $1 "\ncategory = " $2 "\nsubcat = " $3 "\nname = " $4}'
```

I'll break it apart so others may improve / modify

```
find /earth
```

find simply dumps a listing of all the contents of the /earth directory

```
sed -e 's/\// /'
```

I'm replaced all the forward slashes with the space character so I can easily break apart the words. I could do without this step by telling awk to use the forward slash as the delimiter, but this may (or may not) by useful to future revision, so I leave it.

```
awk '{ print .... }'
```

I'm telling awk to print the input it's given with the various categories listed in the question. $1 means the first token. $2 the second token and so on. awk understands lines breaks as well "\n".

I'm not sure what to do if you have several subcategories, however this should get you close.